# Contact Form 7 add special id

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am currently using a code in my contact form 7 for a select drop-down menu. but the thing is I didn't use [select* ..... ] tag. I used an HTML code and I don't see the id of that HTML code in my Mail tab.
**How can I receive the selected option in my email:**

```
<label>Topic</label><select id="your-topic" required>
<option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
<option value="my-account">My Account</option>
<option value="rewards-program">Rewards Program</option>
<option value="product">Product</option>
<option value="shipping">Shipping</option>
<option value="returns">Returns</option>
<option value="other">Other</option></select>
```

Comment: You need to use [select] tag for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't necessarily see the mail tag in contact form 7 mail tab, but you can use the tag by name if you include the name.  Additionally, it won't be required, since CF7 uses ajax validation and submission, the `required` attribute won't help.  But to do what you want, you can do this:

```
<label>Topic</label>
<select id="your-topic" name="your-topic">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
    <option value="my-account">My Account</option>
    <option value="rewards-program">Rewards Program</option>
    <option value="product">Product</option>
    <option value="shipping">Shipping</option>
    <option value="returns">Returns</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Then in the mail tab put `[your-topic]` which will read the options.

Comment: Thank you so much :)